# How to insert value in MySQL by dreamweaver

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have "se" database and "client" table have 5 fields is User_ID,User_Name, User_Pass, Name, Status

**My Table**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="register.php">

<input name="txtUsername" type="text" id="txtUsername">
<input name="email" type="text" id="email">
<td><input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword">
```

**Register.php**

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234") ;
$objDB = mysql_select_db("se");
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO `client` ";
$strSQL .="(`User_ID`,`User_Name`,`User_Pass`,`Name`,`Status`) ";
$strSQL .="VALUES ";
$strSQL .="('3','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["txtPassword"]."' ";
$strSQL .=",'".$_POST["txtUsername"]."','USER') ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if($objQuery)
{
echo "Save Done.";
}else
{
echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]";
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

when I Run this code  and insert somthing in it  this code will "Error Save[............]"

Comment: Your database is MySQL. phpMyAdmin is just a web based interface for managing it.

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a GUI

Comment: Also, use mysqli_ for the connection and actions, the mysql_ way is deprecated.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Its funny to see that all the answers warn about the use of mysql_* functions but keep displaying the code with mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) to get the error message related to your query:

```
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if($objQuery) {
    echo "Save Done.";
} else {
    echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]" . mysql_error();
}
```

FYI, [`mysql_*` functions shouldn't be used in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pw', 'se');

$email        = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password     = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']);
$textUsername = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['txtUsername']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO client (User_ID, User_Name, User_Pass, Name, Status) VALUES (3, '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$textUsername."', 'USER')";
$result= $mysqli -> query($sql);
$num   = $mysqli -> affected_rows;

if($num == 1){
   echo 'Inserted OK!';
}else{
   echo $mysqli -> error;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

You should always make sure that your SQL inserts / updates are properly escaped as this can cause vulnerabilities (SQL Injection). Another method of doing the above is by using prepared statements.

Finally:

> [`mysql_*` functions shouldn't be used in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).